# Pythonic way to update a column of a Polars data frame based on matching condition from another column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, python-polars

In Polars, what is an one-liner way to update items of a column based on matching condition from another column, may by applying lambda?

For example, I would like to multiply items in `col1` with `1000` if items in `col2` are equal to `'a'`. Here's a crude way.

```
import polars as pl

df = pl.DataFrame({
                    'col1':[1,2,3,4],
                    'col2':['a', 'a', 'b', 'b'], 
                    'col3':[10.9, 12.0, 33.3, 34.4]
                    })

y_updated = []
for i in range(df.shape[0]):
    row = df[i]
    if row['col2'][0]=='a':
        y_updated.append(row['col1'][0]*1e3)
    else:
        y_updated.append(row['col1'][0])

df = df.with_columns(pl.lit(y_updated).alias('col1'))
print(df)
```

Outputs -

[image]

Comment: This can be done with [polars.when](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.when.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can update values conditionally using [polars.when](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.when.html)

```py
df.with_columns(
    pl.when(pl.col("col2").eq("a"))
    .then(pl.col("col1") * pl.lit(1000))
    .otherwise(pl.col("col1"))
)

# Output

# shape: (4, 3)
# ┌──────┬──────┬──────┐
# │ col1 ┆ col2 ┆ col3 │
# │ ---  ┆ ---  ┆ ---  │
# │ i64  ┆ str  ┆ f64  │
# ╞══════╪══════╪══════╡
# │ 1000 ┆ a    ┆ 10.9 │
# │ 2000 ┆ a    ┆ 12.0 │
# │ 3    ┆ b    ┆ 33.3 │
# │ 4    ┆ b    ┆ 34.4 │
# └──────┴──────┴──────┘
```

Comment: just a note that you don't have to use `eq`, the `when` can parse `pl.col('col2')=="a"`